# Search price with currency in the text with RegEx

Tags: regex

I need to matches the text that contains the price with currency, but without double currency.

I try this regular expression:

```
(\d+[\.,]*\d*)([eurEUR]{3})[^eurEUR]{3}
```

Here are some examples of how this expression works and how I want to work.

**1.** **The expression works correctly**. Because another currency is just behind the currency.

```
some text before 25,00EUR EUR some text after with
```

**2**. **The expression does not works correctly**. The first char after "EUR" is "e", so the expression does not match.

```
some text before 25,00EUR end some text after with
```

How do I edit an expression that does not match double EUR, but match word starting with letter "e","u" or "r"?

Comment: Are these also the cases you should consider: `Eur, eUr...etc.` which programming language/regex engine do you use? is there a case-insensitive flag/option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use alternative of literals instead of sets with repetitioncounts `[eurEUR]` -> `(eur|EUR)`
2. If you want to ensure that a currency is not followed by a string use negative lookahead: `(?!=eur|EUR)`

Final regex is:

```
(\d+[\.,]*\d*)(eur|EUR) (?!=eur|EUR)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wPj1G2/1)

Comment: It writes me: You can accept an answer in 5 minutes

Comment: I see, I forgot about this timer :)